# Docker build inconsistency for VueJS with GitlabCI

Tags: docker, vue.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, vue-cli

Using Gitlab CI, I'm trying to build docker images for a VueJS application. `.gitlab-ci.yml` file as follows:

```yaml
image: docker
services:
  - docker:dind
stages: 
  - staging
  - deploy

staging:
  stage: staging
  tags: [staging]
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg env=staging -t npmmc/router-control .
    - docker stop router-control || true && docker rm router-control || true
    - docker run -d -p 4001:8080 --restart unless-stopped --env NODE_ENV=staging --name router-control npmmc/router-control

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags: [production]
  when: manual
  only: 
    - master
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg env=production -t npmmc/router-control .
    - docker stop router-control || true && docker rm router-control || true
    - docker run -d -p 4001:8080 --restart unless-stopped --env NODE_ENV=production --name router-control npmmc/router-control
```

And `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

ARG env=development
ENV NODE_ENV=${env}

RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --progress=false
COPY . .
RUN NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV} npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["http-server", "dist"]
```

The `staging` step builds and runs without any problems. The `production` step fails with the error `sh: vue-cli-service: not found`. I'm not understanding what is different between them, when I'm building the exact same docker image a second time for production after it has been tested. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it fail in this line of docker build: `RUN NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV} npm run build` ?

Answer (score 0):

When run with an environment variable `NODE_ENV` set to `production` **npm will not install packages listed as the "devDependencies"**. Quote from the [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install):

> With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies. To install all modules listed in both dependencies and devDependencies when NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production, you can use --production=false.

So, the solution to your problem would be either:

- To move `ENV NODE_ENV=${env}` line a bit down, so it's **after** the line with `RUN npm install --progress=false`,
- To replace `RUN npm install --progress=false` with `RUN npm install --progress=false --production=false` (added `--production=false` flag).